# How to differ pipelines triggered from Merge Request creation from triggered from push to existing Merge Request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to create a job which run only if merge request were created.
But, according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html, merge request pipelines are triggered when:

1. You create a MR.
2. You push commits to existing MR.

The `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` has equal value in both cases ('merge_request_event').

How can i differ those two types of MR events to use it in a job rules?

Comment: Note that merge requests don't exist in base Git; they're a feature of GitLab specifically. I rather doubt that there is a way to distinguish these cases, but that too is specific to GitLab, which I have not actually used. I changed your [tag:git] tag to [tag:gitlab].